# Django DetailView get one record from QuerySet

Tags: django

Please help me get one record from QuerySet object.
views.py:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
from django.http import JsonResponse,
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from movies.models import Book

class BooksMixin(ListView):
    model = Book
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_queryset(self):
        books = Book.objects.values().annotate(authors=ArrayAgg('authors__name',distinct=True)
        return books

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return JsonResponse(context)

class BooksDetail(BooksMixin, DetailView):

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        context = queryset.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from books import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('books/<uuid:pk>/', views.BooksDetail.as_view()),
    ]
```

This works, but I want to get one record from the `queryset` inside the `BooksDetail` class more elegantly, without using the `kwargs['pk']` filter. I tried to use construct like

```
class BooksDetail(BooksMixin, DetailView):
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        context = super(BooksDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bla'] = queryset
        return context
```

but got the error:

```
'BooksDetail' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Comment: Please provide full Stack Trace of error

Comment: I've fixed it. The problem was in the inheritance  of BooksMixin from ListView